How can I drop a row from a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame by index name?
I have a dataframe that looks like:
              GBPEUR
date                
2018-06-22  1.140732
2018-06-25  1.135847
2018-06-26  1.134301
1900-01-01       NaN

df.columns: Index(['GBPEUR'], dtype='object')
df.index: Index([2018-06-22, 2018-06-25, 2018-06-26, 1900-01-01], dtype='object', name='date')
I am trying to do:
df = df.drop(index='1900-01-01')

But I run into:
KeyError: "['1900-01-01'] not found in axis"

I am really confused, isn't 1900-01-01 in the axis?

The object dtype is not necessarily a string. Can you print(df.index.map(type)) ?

Ahhhhh I seee.. I get: Index([<class 'datetime.date'>, <class 'datetime.date'>,        <class 'datetime.date'>, <class 'datetime.date'>],       dtype='object', name='date')

It works now when I key it with a datetime.date object rather than string, thank you!

If the index values are of type datetime.date, you can select them using pandas.Timestamp:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "date": ["2018-06-22", "2018-06-25", "2018-06-26", "1900-01-01"],
    "GBPEUR": [1.140732, 1.135847, 1.134301, None],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.date
df.set_index("date", inplace=True)

df = df.drop(index=pd.Timestamp("1900-01-01"))

              GBPEUR
date                
2018-06-22  1.140732
2018-06-25  1.135847
2018-06-26  1.134301

